# Cross Join and Left Outer Join of Tables in Database

Tags: sql, join

I have three table in my database

**Employee Table**

- EmployeeId **(PK)**
- Last Name

**Question Table**

- Qid **(PK)**
- Question

**Questionnaire**

- QuestionnaireId **(PK)**
- QId **(FK)**
- EmployeeId **(FK)**
- Response
- Details

This is the SQL Query that I write on my own, but it is producing an output that I do not need

```
 Select q.qid,e.employeeId, q.Question, eq.response 
 from employee e 
 cross join Question q
 left outer join employeequestionnaire eq on q.Qid= eq.Qid
 where e.employeeId = 1
```

**This is the output**

```
             Qid   EmployeeId        Question       Response 
             "1"       "1"          "Question1"     "0"
             "1"       "1"          "Question1"     "1"
             "2"       "1"          "Question2"     "1"
             "2"       "1"          "Question2"     "0"
             "3"       "1"          "Question3"     "1"
             "4"       "1"          "Question4"     NULL
```

But I need this kind of Output

```
             Qid    EmployeeId       Question       Response  
             "1"       "1"          "Question1"     "0"
             "2"       "1"          "Question2"     "1"
             "3"       "1"          "Question3"     "1"
             "4"       "1"          "Question4"     NULL
```

I am a newbie in SQL, sorry for my sample query..

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your output or with your query, as one of them has `EmployeeID` as a number while the other has it as a string.

Comment: I'm thinking you might be missing a necessary table here.  You should probably have one table that defines which questions are in a Questionnaire and another table to store the responses.  Otherwise it's impossible to tell which questions are in a Questionnaire if someone doesn't answer all the questions (hope that's clear..)

Comment: @JackManey - sorry, I put a wrong header with the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `employeequestionnaire` has the employeeID field, you don't need the `employee` table.  I think you can just do:

```
Select q.qid, eq.employeeId, q.Question, eq.response 
from Question q left outer join
     employeequestionnaire eq
     on q.Qid= eq.Qid and
        eq.employeeId = 1
```

Notice that I moved the `where` clause into an `on` clause.  This is sometimes necessary when using a `left outer join`.

If you wanted to include information about employees from that table, you would use not use a `cross join`:

```
Select q.qid, eq.employeeId, q.Question, eq.response 
from Question q left outer join
     employeequestionnaire eq
     on q.Qid= eq.Qid and
        eq.employeeId = 1 left outer join
     employees e
     on e.EmployeeID = eq.EmployeeID
```